# Definition of an Ordered Field

Tags: real-analysis, definition

A text I'm looking at has the following definition of an ordered field:

> DEFINITION A field ($F$, $+$, $\cdot$) is **ordered** iff there is a relation $\lt$ on $F$ such that for all $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad x,y,z\in F,$
>
> (1) $x\not\lt x$ (irreflexivity)
>   (2) if $x\lt y$ and $y\lt z$, then $x\lt z$ (transitivity)
>   (3) either $x\lt y$, $x=y$, or $y\lt x$ (trichotomy)
>   (4) if $x\lt y$, then $x+z\lt y+z$
>   (5) if $x\lt y$ and $0\lt z$, then $x\cdot z\lt y\cdot z$
>
> $\quad$ Taken together, these properties ensure that the field elements are linearly arranged, and that the ordering is compatible with the operations of addition and multiplication.

(Also, in another text that I'm using the definition appears with (1) omitted.)

The text says that these properties ensure that the field elements are linearly arranged, which makes me think of the definition of a linear order (or a total order). According to the same text, a linear order is a partial ordering $R$ on a set $A$ with the property that every two elements are comparable. Thus, a linear order (which I'm assuming $\lt$ is for $F$ in the definition above) is one that is reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive, and also satisfies totality (or comparability).

Assuming I'm correct that $\lt$ is a total order on $F$, then how does it meet the definition of a total order, when for instance it does not satisfy totality and isn't reflexive?

Comment: You are thinking to hard.  It *is* a total order and the author of the text is using properties 1-3 as a definition of total order and, as NS, answers these definitions are equivalent to the ones you are familiar with.  BTW axioms 4 and 5 are what distinguish an "ordered field" from "a field with an order".

Comment: @fleablood (1)-(3) are the properties of a strict total order, which is different from a linear or total order, right?

Comment: On second reading I think you are right. < is a strict total order which is not refexive.  It's not a linear order which is reflexive.  $\le $ is a linear or total order but non-strict.  < is linear arranged but not what is called a linear order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is defining a *strict order*, that is a relation that is *irreflexive* and *transitive*. In this case, totality is expressed by trichotomy.

You get a “standard” order relation by defining
$$
x\le y \quad\text{for}\quad x<y\text{ or }x=y
$$
Such a relation is indeed reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive and also a total order that satisfies

- if $x\le y$, then $x+z\le y+z$
- if $x\le y$ and $0\le z$, then $xz\le yz$.

---

In general, strict orders and orders are essentially the same thing. A strict order on $X$ is a relation $R$ that's *irreflexive* ($x\mathrel{R}x$ holds for no element) and transitive.

If $R$ is a strict order on $X$, then $S=R\cup\Delta_X$ is an order on $X$, where $\Delta_X=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. Similarly, if $S$ is an order on $X$, then $R=S\setminus\Delta_X$ is a strict order.

In the case above, $\le$ is the order associated to the strict order $<$.

Comment: Allow me to sum up. A strict order $R$ is a relation that is irreflexive and transitive. If $R$ also satisfies trichotomy (at least one of $aRb, a=b, bRa$ holds, for every $a,b,c$ in our set we are considering), then it is a strict total order. A (non-strict) order $S$ (which I've been calling a linear order or a total order) is one that is reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive, and satisfies totality ($aSb$ or $bSa$, for every a,b in the set we are considering). Both $R$ and $S$ ensure that the elements are linearly arranged.

Comment: @K.Hotz Correct, they're two ways of describing the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your order is reflexive by combining axioms (1) and (3).

And isn't Axiom (3) totality?

Note that (1) can be omitted if "either" in Axiom 3 is replaced by "exactly one of"

Comment: So far, I've only been able to show that < is antisymmetric, trivially. How can it be that < is reflexive, if by (1) it is irreflexive?

Comment: @K.Hotz And there lies your confusion. It is not $<$ which is the order, it is $\leq$. Define the order this way, and everything will work properly.